# Docker compose usage of external firebird service

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, firebird

The architecture of the app I planning to create consist of an React, Python and Firebird component. The React part will serve as front-end, the Python part will be the back-end which communicates with the Firebird DB. The React and Firebird component will run in Docker and has to communicate with a Firebird server, which runs locally on 127.0.0.1.

The current docker-compose file looks like the following:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  gui:
    build:
      context: gui
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - api

  api:
    build:
      context: api
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 3050:3050
    volumes:
      - C:/Program Files/Firebird/Firebird_2_5/examples/empbuild:/app/api/empbuild:rw
```

For connecting to the local Firebird server, the following code can be used:

```py
import firebirdsql

conn = firebirdsql.connect(
    host='127.0.0.1',
    database='...',
    port=3050,
    user='sysdba',
    password='masterkey'
)
```

So, I need to establish a connection to the local network within the docker container to 127.0.0.1:3050. Currently I'm getting the following error:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Which is due to that the Firebird service is running outside the container and is not mapped to the network of the docker containers. How can I establish this connection by having those two components communicating with the Local Firebird sever?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 inside a Docker container refers to that Docker container, not to the host running Docker, use `host.docker.internal` instead of `127.0.0.1` if you want to connect to the host itself. Your definition of API (especially the declaration of ports `3050:3050` and the volume mapping the example database folder, suggests that the Firebird service is running on API, which contradicts your description in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you [can't access host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) from docker container using `127.0.0.1`.

Second, if your Firebird is run on host, you shouldn't expose port 3050 from your `api` container. And even if it runs inside `api` container, you still shouldn't expose it: use default network created by docker compose, to connect from `gui` to `api` using introduced DNS record: `api`.